# static property error type, type Hourly TableViewCell has no member "identifier"

Tags: swift

I creates a cell and declared a property like this

```
import UIKit

class HourlyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {

super.awakeFromNib()
// Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
// Configure the view for the selected state

}

static let indentifier = "HourlyTableViewCell"
static func nib() -> UINib {

return UINib(nibName: "HourlyTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

}

}
```

In the Viewcontroller I coded it like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
var models = [Weather]()
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // Register two cells

table.register(HourlyTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier:HourlyTableViewCell.identifier)

table.register(WeatherTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: WeatherTableViewCell.identifier)

table.delegate = self    
table.dataSource = self

}

// Table

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
return UITableViewCell()
 }

}



struct Weather {

}
```

When I try to run it I get an error

Type HourlyTableView Controller has no member "identifier"

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Answer (score 0):

in HourlyTableViewCell, you have **indentifier**

```
static let indentifier = "HourlyTableViewCell"
```

in ViewController, you use **identifier**

```
table.register(HourlyTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier:HourlyTableViewCell.identifier)
```